# Prove that for any $f,g$ polynomials in a polynomial ring, there are no zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

How would one prove the following where $f,g$ are polynomials (First, when they are polynomials in a single unknown. Second, when they are polynomials in multiple unknowns):

If $f,g\neq0$ in $\mathbb{K}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ prove that $f\cdot g \neq 0$ -- i.e. $\mathbb{K}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ has no "zero divisors".

I notice that for any given $f\cdot g$, there is always one monomial of the highest degree that is not the sum of products, thus neither $f$ nor $g$ can be a zero divisor. But how would a proof follow from this?

Comment: That observation takes care of the case $n=1$, and (with a few additional words) of the induction step.(Presumably, it has not been mentioned but should be, $K$ is a field.)

Comment: What is $\mathbb K$? If you take it as a ring having no zero divisors, then you can use an induction. [Note also that if you have infinitely many $x_i$ the product of two polynomials can be considered in a context with only finitely many to consider]

Comment: You are missing the necessary (and sufficient) hypothesis that the coefficient ring is also a domain.